# how to wrap a context with next

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-context

I haven't used next.js or react for a long time, I'm under the impression that the context api is very different. This code here contains all the logic that I need to access on several pages. But despite exporting the SearchContext, it is not being recognized in the return (Cannot find namespace 'SearchContext'.ts(2503))
How is context working nowadays?

```
import { createContext, useState } from "react";
import { imoveis } from "@/app/data/imoveis";

export const SearchContext = createContext({});

export const SearchProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [select1Value, setSelect1Value] = useState("Rent");
  const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState<any[]>([]);

  const handleSelect1Change = (e: any) => {
    setSelect1Value(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleSearch = () => {
    const produtosFiltrados = imoveis.filter((product) => {
      return product.tipo === select1Value;
    });

    const resultados = produtosFiltrados.map((product) => ({
      title: product.title,
      price: product.price,
      tipo: product.tipo,
      path: product.path,
    }));
    setSearchResults(resultados);
  };

  return (
    <SearchContext.Provider
      value={{
        select1Value,
        searchResults,
        handleSelect1Change,
        handleSearch,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </SearchContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Comment: You didn't follow the sequence, let me share it with you here

You are using TS, so
1. Create an `interface` for `const cntx = createContext`
2. Create a pure component that will return actual context through `useContext()`
3. Finally, create a provider with all of the available methods which you already defined in the `ref 1 (`interface`)`

If you don't understand after reading this mass, no prob. I can help you